# How to verify client using a python flask API

Tags: python

I'm running python flask and have an end point say /api/secure.
Right now anyone can access it using Basic Auth over HTTPS.
In my case customers will use this to get their specific data.
The problem I have is that I don't know that the client that connects to this api is actually the customer we send the username/psw to.

So I have been googling this for awhile now and havn't found a good solution for it.
Since the client that connects will be a batchprogram  (so no real user) then I guess oauth and json web tokens is not what I am after?
My idea could be that the client would supply a certificate in the request and that we on our end can compare this certificate with something we have saved when we setup the account for the customer.
I have been looking at mutual authentication like [mutual-tls-with-python-flask-and-werkzeug](https://www.ajg.id.au/2018/01/01/mutual-tls-with-python-flask-and-werkzeug/) but I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Is there a best practise how to handle this?

Comment: You can try digital signature authorisation

Comment: there is no real solution that protects you against the customer passing his credentials to someone else.